Same Bruhat-Tits buildings for different groups
In dimension 1 it can happen, that two p-adic groups share the same Bruhat-Tits building as the latter are highly symmetric trees.
Can the same happen in higher dimensions as well?
If it happens, is it always the case that one group is over a field of positive characteristic and the other over a field of characteristic zero?
Is there a good general understanding of how often it happens?

In rank $\ge 2$ the group of automorphisms of a discrete irreducible affine building is essentially commensurable to the corresponding simple algebraic group (you may have to add field automorphisms).

@Moishe Kohan: Thank you! Can you give a reference?
